# Get object data outside for loop in C#

Tags: c#

I'm really new to C#, I started with Javascript so it's a bit of a struggle to understand the behaviour of C#.

I am trying to create a simple object inside my for loop and then display the assigned value afterwards but there is a scope issue with this, and am unclear on how I can then access it outside of the for loop?

This is my code setup:

```
public class Player{
    public int identity;
    public int score;

    public Player(int id){
        identity = id;
        score    = 0;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        Player player = new Player(i);
}

//here i want to access a player and print the information for said player
```

I don't know how i can access the newly created players outside of the loop, how is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can understand how this could be confusing coming from JavaScript, in JavaScript all your variables are hoisted to the function (or global) scope.  That's not true in C#, in C# variables are generally scoped within the nearest set of `{}`s.  But are available for use within child scopes.

So you could write your code like this:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
Player player = null;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        player = new Player(i);
        players.Add(player);
}
Console.WriteLine(players[x]);
```

In this example you would have access to each individual `player` outside of the `foreach` because it's declared at the higher scope. But this would be more appropriately written:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        Player player = new Player(i);
        players.Add(player);
}
Console.WriteLine(players[x]);
```

It's generally considered good practice to declare your variables as close to their usage as you can.

A final optimisation, that you yourself suggested, would be to eliminate the `player` declaration completely (as it's unnecessary) and inline it.  That leaves us with the final version:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        players.Add(new Player(i));
}
Console.WriteLine(players[x]);
```

Comment: Sorry by "a player" i meant any of the players i created for further usage in a script. for example i may want player number 5.

Comment: @WDUK No problem, I have a tendancy to take things quite literally. :)

Comment: Can this be simplified with `players.Add(new Player(i));` or do i have to assign to `Player player` first?

Comment: @WDUK Yes, absolutely, I was trying to preserve the separate declarations in order to help you better understand how the scopes work, but that would be a perfect "optimization".

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this

```
Player player = new Player();
List<Player> playerlist = new List<Player>();

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
      player   = new Player(i);
      playerlist.Add(player);
}
```

Comment: He wouldn't need the instantiation of the player var, but close enough.

Comment: So i don't need to set "player" var as `Player` type in my loop either?

Comment: @WDUK you could just create the player object in the loop like:
playerlist.add(new Player(i));